# How to update a userform label once range selected via refedit

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a userform with 2 refedit boxes. They both allow the user to select a cell. I have a label underneath each refedit that i would like to show the text of a specific cell on that row (not necessarily the selected cell), I guess it would be something like:

```
Range("D" & Range(Refedit1.Value).Row)
```

or similar (Any suggestions/improvements on this appreciated)

My question is: how do I get this to update every time a new cell is selected? I've read that refedit is buggy and can break easily if it is made too complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this - handle the refedit's `Change` event:

```
Private Sub RefEdit1_Change()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range(Me.RefEdit1.Value).Cells(1) 'in case >1 cell selected
    Debug.Print rng.EntireRow.Cells(4).Value    'col D on that row
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, should the third line be: Me.Label3.Caption = rng.EntireRow.Cells(4).Value ?

Comment: Might want to add some error handling in case there's no range selected